# How to "count" user inputs from a Controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, controller, ruby-on-rails-4, mvp

I have a **@shows** Controller where every user can create a Show (*Singular*).

On the Show Creation View (*shows/new*) i want to display a counter of how many shows there are already.

i tried:

```
def count
  @shows.all.count
end
# in my Shows Controller
```

and then called `<%= @count %>` on my view. But i guess this isn't the right way.

I tried calling it directly on my View:

```
<%= @shows.count %>
```

but neither this worked.

Can someone help me out ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`@show_count = Show.count` will do your job.

In your view `<%= @show_count%>`

Comment: Cool Worked :), if i want to display it in another view from another model can i just do the same ?

Comment: yes, e.g. for users count `@user_count = User.count` and in View `<%= @user_count%>`

Answer (score 0):

You need to create the @count variable in your `new` method in the controller or use a helper method from your view

**controller version**

```
def new
    # your other code here

    @count = Shows.count
    # @count is now available in your view for `new`
end
```

You could always simply call `<%= @shows.count %>` inside your view.
Yes, you should only do minimal code stuff in your view but this is just a simple call, not a method chain doing complex things, so it's alright to do that.

With the code given, I cannot say why `@shows.count` didn't work for you in the view. Maybe you forgot to add the `.all` in your controller?

Comment: Thanks for answering, i already got Bachan's answer as it worked :) But thanks for answering.