# How to set up a Count from my Controller in Rails

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, database, view

I'm new to ruby on rails so please forgive the question. I tried following this example [How to "count" user inputs from a Controller](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18764418/how-to-count-user-inputs-from-a-controller][1]) but kept getting nothing in my view. I am trying to create a count functionality on my share feature (similar to retweet which works perfectly now). >> So whenever a user shares a tweet there is a counter that changes with it as well. I have listed below all my relevant code. Thank you so much guys!!

**tweets_controller.rb**

```
class TweetsController < ApplicationController
 before_action :set_tweet, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy, :share]
 def index    
  @tweets = Tweet.all
 end
 def share
  tweet = current_user.tweets.create(tweet_id: @tweet.id)
  if tweet.save
    redirect_to tweets_path
  else
    redirect_to :back, alert: "Unable to share"
  end
end
```

**_share.html.erb**

```
 <div>
<div>Shared by <%= tweet.user.username %></div>
<%= render partial: "tweets/tweet", locals: {tweet: tweet.tweet} %>
</div>
```

**_tweet.html.erb**

```
<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-3"><%= tweet.watches_count %><%= render partial: "watches", locals: {tweet: tweet} %></div>
<div class="col-md-3"><%= link_to '<i class="fa fa-share fa-lg" aria-hidden="true"></i>'.html_safe, share_tweet_path(tweet), method: :post  %></div>
<div class="col-md-6"><span class="pull-right"><%= tweet.likes_count %><%= render partial: "likes", locals: {tweet: tweet} %></span></div>
</div>
</div>
```

**routes.rb**

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
 resources :tweets do
    resource :like, module: :tweets
    resource :watch, module: :tweets
    member do
     post :share
    end
 end
 devise_for :users, :controllers => { :omniauth_callbacks => "users/omniauth_callbacks" }
 resources :users, :controllers => "users_controller.rb"
 root to: "tweets#index"
end
```

**Migration CreateTweets**

```
class CreateTweets < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.0]
 def change
  create_table :tweets do |t|
   t.text :body
   t.integer :user_id
   t.integer :tweet_id
   t.timestamps
  end
 end
end
```

**Relevant Rake Routes**

```
 share_tweet POST     /tweets/:id/share(.:format)              tweets#share
 tweets      GET      /tweets(.:format)                        tweets#index
            POST     /tweets(.:format)                        tweets#create
```

Comment: Can you please fix the indenting?

Comment: Max thank you so much for taking a look. I have fixed all the indenting. My apologies for how it was before

Comment: I believe there are a number of things gone awry with your code that may be causing the problem. For starters, can you run the `rake routes` command? Judging from your controller code, you are redirecting towards your index path when a user hits the `share` route of your controller. This means that you are rendering by default `app/views/tweets/index.html.erb` When you say you see nothing it is probably because you aren't rendering the `_share.html.erb` partial in `index.html.erb`

Comment: Dan thank you so much for your response. I have included the relevant rake routes above. Just to clarify I'm able to retweet, but I would like to do is show how many users have retweet a specific tweet